# Google ReCaptcha Front-End Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I want to use Google ReCaptcha but i also dont't want to touch server side or back-end code.

I am using ASP.Net MVC but i also don't want to use any package from nuget or any library. Solution must be front-end only. All javascript/jquery solutions are accepted.

I also note that my forms are collecting data and sending it as an e-mail to specified mailbox. I am also not using any 3rd party library for this process. It is manually coded only by ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: use java script, grecaptcha.getResponse()

Comment: The important part of a solution such as Google's Recaptcha is the communication with the server-side. This is because front-end code can easily be read, cracked or even outright replaced. Let's say you have `captcha_challenge()`, which returns `true` if the user manages to solve the captcha. Now I go into the source and replace your function with `function captcha_challenge() { return true; }`. I click the button again and I'm in. There's really no point in implementing something like a captcha or password encryption on the front-end only. You *need* a back-end for it to work securely.

Comment: Hello, according to Google recommendation, a Google recaptcha has two steps. The first step is the UI integration. The second step is the back-end integration. Without the back-end integration, you would not have the total benefit of google recaptcha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Ivo Coumans for detailed explanation. I got it working but obvously it is not safe. Rinto Antony gave me an idea here is what i do.

I am calling the Google ReCaptcha API to head section of my website and adding the div that creates the captcha:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="api_key" data-callback="enableBtn"></div>
```

Since data-callback is triggering enableBtn function, it is possible to take action if it is returning true. So i have added a disabled submit button to my form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Gönder" id="button1" disabled>
```

Then i have added a simple javascript to enable it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableBtn() {
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

I am aware that this can be easily bypassed and not a real solution but it is working. I am open to any ideas that can make this better.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are using a CMS , you will have to put some code in the backend since you will making a POST request with the reCAPTCHA.

I highly recommend wordpress as it will be a matter of just downloading a plugin and then just copying the keys and pasting them.

Comment: Comment only. Put solution please

Comment: Any comments should be added as a comment to the original question. If you have a solution, then add the code as a solution. PS: You can not have a complete solution using Google recaptcha using only UI validation. However, that is not the point here. The point is , please add your comment as a comment to the original question and not as a solution unless you have one.